# pandas date time function on multiple columns timezones

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe z2 with columns utc_time and timezone. I want to make a new column that takes the UTC epoch time and returns date time based on the timezone in column timezone. I am also using the function timezone from pytz. I want to apply this function below to the whole data frame (a few million long) in reasonable runtime. I've tried using assign and apply but it gives me a 'Series' object has no attribute 'upper' error

```
datetime.fromtimestamp((z2['utc_time'][0])/1000, timezone(str(z2['timezone'][0]))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]? Is the time zone different for each timestamp?

Comment: Just curious to know if your error gets solved by removing str() function. Of course, a reproducible example would help.

Comment: The timezones fall into the four US timezones, represented as a string, like 'America/Chicago' . the str() doesn't change anything, the function works when I do it to one row of data. The problem seems to be the "apply". Are there any alternatives to Apply that could run function based on two columns of data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 4 timezones, you should be fine with looping those. You can use `.loc` to select the according rows and localize. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
# example df:
df = pd.DataFrame({'UTCtime': ['2020-03-01T12:00:00', '2020-07-01T12:00:00'],
                   'Timezone': ['US/Pacific', 'US/Eastern']})

# parse strings to UTC first:
df['UTCtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UTCtime'], utc=True)

# create a dummy column to avoid key error:
df['LOCtime'] = False

# loop unique time zones and fill local time column:
for tz in df['Timezone'].unique():
    df['LOCtime'].loc[df['Timezone']==tz] = df['UTCtime'].loc[df['Timezone']==tz].dt.tz_convert(tz)
```

gives you e.g.

```
df
                    UTCtime    Timezone                    LOCtime
0 2020-03-01 12:00:00+00:00  US/Pacific  2020-03-01 04:00:00-08:00
1 2020-07-01 12:00:00+00:00  US/Eastern  2020-07-01 08:00:00-04:00
```

---

Another option might be to use `.apply` with a `lambda`. Makes a nice 1-liner but I'd guesstimate that this is not as efficient:

```
df['LOCtime'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['UTCtime'].tz_convert(r['Timezone']), axis=1)
```

Comment: the above code only runs when you switch tz_convert to tz_localize

Comment: @chez: that would mean that your input is not localized (to UTC) - check my example, I already localize to UTC; after that, you need to use `tz_convert` (pandas 1.0.5).

Comment: Huh, I did and it still tells me that. Which code localizes input?

Comment: @chez: it is `utc=True` in `pd.to_datetime(df['UTCtime'], utc=True)`. you should be fine however with not doing this and `tz_localize` as you say since pandas treats naive datetime as UTC by default. But make sure to test this.

Comment: It works, Thank you. I do get the Settingwithcopy warning though. And it's having trouble with ambiguous times

Comment: @chez: to avoid such lengthy discussions in the comments, it is best to provide a [mre]... Anyhow, you could either ignore the warning or try if it isn't raised if you use `assign`. Concerning ambiguous times, this is exactly why I localize to UTC first.